# Why Android Studio update SDK is listing files from my mobile phone that is not connected anymore?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

I used my mobile phone sometimes as debug device and an emulator whose has PlayStore but only that, nothing more, not even my account from Google. So upon trying to update A.S. it started taking longer, so I take a look at it and he is listing files from my mobile phone that was not connected via USB to the computer neither other ways.

What does my phone files has to do with android update? And the updates is taking forever running through all files from my phone, it appeared system/ WhatsApp/ Downloads/ etc with files I know for sure are only in my personal device not the emulator.

Why does A.S. list these files on Update?

[image: Android Studio update window]

Comment: That path isnt even a normal android path you would find on a device, that path is probably a path on your computer

Comment: So tried to search for this folder and so I found it inside \AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\ the folder (my name) with literally a copy of my phone..... but why? And Android Studio was running through all that files to update the SDK.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a copy of my files inside \AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\ and AndroidStudio maybe thought it was important to look at it. Resolved by removing the files inside the folder with my name.